# AWS CLI ALB create target group error with lambda as a target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-alb

looking for some help on why this is failing

`aws elbv2 create-target-group --name $targetName --target-type lambda`

returns

`aws: error: the following arguments are required: --protocol, --port, --vpc-id`

if i supply protocol, port & vpc-id

`aws elbv2 create-target-group --name $targetName --target-type lambda --protocol HTTPS --port 443 --vpc-id vpc-1234`

returns

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateTargetGroup operation: Port cannot be specified for target groups with target type 'lambda'`

I'm stuck, i've tried json file input with the same result. once you create the target group you can't change target-type (i tried creating a https then edit it the target-type but its not supported)

Comment: Your first command works for me. What version of the CLI do you have? (I have aws-cli/1.16.41)

Comment: i ran the pip3 upgrade command but for some reason it wasn't actually updating to 1.16 (i was on 1.15) after i uninstalled the cli and reinstalled its now working. thanks for making me go through and revalidate the version